# Co-working or Coworking?

Tags: nouns, orthography, hyphenation, prefixes

I'm proofreading a text for the magazine, and came across *coworking*.  I prefer to spell it **co-working** with a hyphen *-*.

I've looked on Ngrams, wikipedia, and several dictionaries, and as usual with punctuation issues this one's all over the map.  People in the office say everyone spells it without a hyphen and that I'm being too picky or old-fashioned.

What are justifications for using or not using a hyphen in **coworking/co-working**?

Comment: Unless you want people to mistakenly associate what you do with fixing udders to milking machines I would suggest a hyphen.

Comment: @WS2 I don't understand

Comment: @michael_timofeev I think WS2 is referring to the first three letters of *coworking*.

Comment: There is a distinct difference between "coworker" and "co-worker".  Assuming that the people involved are not "coworkers" but rather "co-workers", it would be advised to retain the hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

Please see this

> "BiztipWritingTip response: Unfortunately, this question is still being debated. Both the CP (Canadian Press) and the AP (Associated Press) stylebooks recommend co-worker. So does the dictionary associated with the MicroSoft Word program."

But The Chicago Manual of Style and The Economist’s Style Guide (British) suggest that prefixes of one syllable, such as “*co*” can be used to form a single word. **Therefore, coworker is acceptable.**"
http://ontariotraining.net/word-choice-coworker-or-co-worker/
***I personally advocate "co-worker" as a writer.***